# \baselineskip changes values between different computers, even using same Tex editor

Tags: spacing, editors, baseline

My problem is that my .tex file contains many `\baselineskip` and these seem to have a value that changes between different computers. That's what happens in practice: I work on a computer at work using `Texmaker` and then I work on exactly the same .tex file on my computer at home, still using `Texmaker` and while at work when I compiled the spacing between paragraphs was correct, at home everything is messed up. I think I identified the problem being in `\baselineskip`. Any ideas how to set this to a fixed value?

Comment: Are you using the same TeX distro at home and at work? Have you checked that the values are actually different (value comparison)?

Comment: It should also change depending on the font size.

Comment: `\baselineskip` will work the same way in all tex distributions. If you have documents showing different values then you have different tex files setting it to different values. Not directly related to the question but why has your document got "many `\baselineskip` " `\baselineskip` is a tex primitive length but wouldn't normally be referenced directly within a document.

Comment: texmaker is not related to the layout, that is just the editor you are using to write the tex file, it is (for example) pdflatex that is interpreting the tex instructions within your document.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  what is the symptom in the output that shows a difference in `\baselineskip`?  are you printing the output, or only looking at it on the screen?  i have been confused by printed output that used "print to fit" instead of "actual size".  if the page has the same number of lines, and the line breaks are the same, then the apparent difference could be caused by somehing like that.